# Undefined Reference To (linking errors)

Tags: c++, eclipse, mingw

Trying to compile a cpp program in I run into the following linking errors:

```
11:42:55 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project mrconv ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
g++ "-IC:\\Users\\Jesse\\Documents\\Work\\Research\\FiberTracking\\Software\\mrtrix\\source\\mrtrix-0.2.11\\lib" "-IC:\\Users\\Jesse\\Programs\\gtk+\\lib" "-IC:\\Users\\Jesse\\Programs\\gtk+\\bin" "-IC:\\Users\\Jesse\\Programs\\gtk+\\include\\glib-2.0" "-IC:\\Users\\Jesse\\Programs\\gtk+\\lib\\glib-2.0\\include" "-IC:\\gtkmm64\\include\\glibmm-2.4\\glibmm" "-IC:\\gtkmm64\\include\\glibmm-2.4" "-IC:\\gtkmm64\\lib\\glibmm-2.4\\include" "-IC:\\gtkmm64\\include\\sigc++-2.0" "-IC:\\gtkmm64\\lib\\sigc++-2.0\\include" "-IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\GnuWin32\\include" "-IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\GnuWin32\\include\\gsl" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o "src\\mrconvert.o" "..\\src\\mrconvert.cpp" 
g++ "-LC:\\GnuWin32\\lib\\" -o mrconv.exe "src\\mrconvert.o" -llibgsl 
src\mrconvert.o: In function `main':
C:\Users\Jesse\workspace\mrconv\Debug/../src/mrconvert.cpp:119: undefined reference to `MR::App::run(int, char**)'
src\mrconvert.o: In function `ZN5MyApp7executeEv':
C:\Users\Jesse\workspace\mrconv\Debug/../src/mrconvert.cpp:123: undefined reference to `MR::parse_floats(std::string const&)'
C:\Users\Jesse\workspace\mrconv\Debug/../src/mrconvert.cpp:167: undefined reference to `MR::DataType::parse(std::string const&)'
C:\Users\Jesse\workspace\mrconv\Debug/../src/mrconvert.cpp:174: undefined reference to `MR::Image::parse_axes_specifier(MR::Image::Axes const&, std::string const&)'
C:\Users\Jesse\workspace\mrconv\Debug/../src/mrconvert.cpp:201: undefined reference to `MR::parse_ints(std::string const&, int)'
C:\Users\Jesse\workspace\mrconv\Debug/../src/mrconvert.cpp:225: undefined reference to `MR::ProgressBar::init(unsigned int, std::string const&)'
src\mrconvert.o: In function `_static_initialization_and_destruction_0':
C:\Users\Jesse\workspace\mrconv\Debug/../src/mrconvert.cpp:55: undefined reference to `MR::Argument::End'
C:\Users\Jesse\workspace\mrconv\Debug/../src/mrconvert.cpp:95: undefined reference to `MR::Option::End'
src\mrconvert.o: In function `ZNK2MR9Exception7displayEv':
C:/Users/Jesse/Documents/Work/Research/FiberTracking/Software/mrtrix/source/mrtrix-0.2.11/lib/mrtrix.h:187: undefined reference to `MR::Exception::level_offset'
C:/Users/Jesse/Documents/Work/Research/FiberTracking/Software/mrtrix/source/mrtrix-0.2.11/lib/mrtrix.h:187: undefined reference to `MR::error'
C:/Users/Jesse/Documents/Work/Research/FiberTracking/Software/mrtrix/source/mrtrix-0.2.11/lib/mrtrix.h:188: undefined reference to `MR::Exception::level_offset'
C:/Users/Jesse/Documents/Work/Research/FiberTracking/Software/mrtrix/source/mrtrix-0.2.11/lib/mrtrix.h:188: undefined reference to `MR::info'
C:/Users/Jesse/Documents/Work/Research/FiberTracking/Software/mrtrix/source/mrtrix-0.2.11/lib/mrtrix.h:189: undefined reference to `MR::debug'
src\mrconvert.o: In function `ZN2MR11ProgressBar3incEv':
C:/Users/Jesse/Documents/Work/Research/FiberTracking/Software/mrtrix/source/mrtrix-0.2.11/lib/mrtrix.h:451: undefined reference to `MR::ProgressBar::current_val'
C:/Users/Jesse/Documents/Work/Research/FiberTracking/Software/mrtrix/source/mrtrix-0.2.11/lib/mrtrix.h:451: undefined reference to `MR::ProgressBar::current_val'
C:/Users/Jesse/Documents/Work/Research/FiberTracking/Software/mrtrix/source/mrtrix-0.2.11/lib/mrtrix.h:452: undefined reference to `MR::ProgressBar::display'
C:/Users/Jesse/Documents/Work/Research/FiberTracking/Software/mrtrix/source/mrtrix-0.2.11/lib/mrtrix.h:452: undefined reference to `MR::ProgressBar::stop'
C:/Users/Jesse/Documents/Work/Research/FiberTracking/Software/mrtrix/source/mrtrix-0.2.11/lib/mrtrix.h:453: undefined reference to `MR::ProgressBar::multiplier'
C:/Users/Jesse/Documents/Work/Research/FiberTracking/Software/mrtrix/source/mrtrix-0.2.11/lib/mrtrix.h:453: undefined reference to `MR::ProgressBar::stop_watch'
C:/Users/Jesse/Documents/Work/Research/FiberTracking/Software/mrtrix/source/mrtrix-0.2.11/lib/mrtrix.h:453: undefined reference to `Glib::Timer::elapsed() const'
C:/Users/Jesse/Documents/Work/Research/FiberTracking/Software/mrtrix/source/mrtrix-0.2.11/lib/mrtrix.h:453: undefined reference to `MR::ProgressBar::current_val'
C:/Users/Jesse/Documents/Work/Research/FiberTracking/Software/mrtrix/source/mrtrix-0.2.11/lib/mrtrix.h:453: undefined reference to `MR::ProgressBar::multiplier'
C:/Users/Jesse/Documents/Work/Research/FiberTracking/Software/mrtrix/source/mrtrix-0.2.11/lib/mrtrix.h:454: undefined reference to `MR::ProgressBar::percent'
C:/Users/Jesse/Documents/Work/Research/FiberTracking/Software/mrtrix/source/mrtrix-0.2.11/lib/mrtrix.h:455: undefined reference to `MR::ProgressBar::percent'
C:/Users/Jesse/Documents/Work/Research/FiberTracking/Software/mrtrix/source/mrtrix-0.2.11/lib/mrtrix.h:456: undefined reference to `MR::ProgressBar::display_func'
C:/Users/Jesse/Documents/Work/Research/FiberTracking/Software/mrtrix/source/mrtrix-0.2.11/lib/mrtrix.h:458: undefined reference to `MR::ProgressBar::stop'
src\mrconvert.o: In function `ZN2MR11ProgressBar4doneEv':
C:/Users/Jesse/Documents/Work/Research/FiberTracking/Software/mrtrix/source/mrtrix-0.2.11/lib/mrtrix.h:461: undefined reference to `MR::ProgressBar::display'
C:/Users/Jesse/Documents/Work/Research/FiberTracking/Software/mrtrix/source/mrtrix-0.2.11/lib/mrtrix.h:461: undefined reference to `MR::ProgressBar::done_func'
src\mrconvert.o: In function `ZN2MR5Image6ObjectD1Ev':
C:/Users/Jesse/Documents/Work/Research/FiberTracking/Software/mrtrix/source/mrtrix-0.2.11/lib/image/object.h:49: undefined reference to `MR::info'
C:/Users/Jesse/Documents/Work/Research/FiberTracking/Software/mrtrix/source/mrtrix-0.2.11/lib/image/object.h:49: undefined reference to `MR::Image::Mapper::unmap(MR::Image::Header const&)'
C:/Users/Jesse/Documents/Work/Research/FiberTracking/Software/mrtrix/source/mrtrix-0.2.11/lib/image/object.h:49: undefined reference to `MR::Image::Mapper::~Mapper()'
C:/Users/Jesse/Documents/Work/Research/FiberTracking/Software/mrtrix/source/mrtrix-0.2.11/lib/image/object.h:49: undefined reference to `MR::Image::Mapper::~Mapper()'
src\mrconvert.o: In function `ZN2MR5Image6Object3mapEv':
C:/Users/Jesse/Documents/Work/Research/FiberTracking/Software/mrtrix/source/mrtrix-0.2.11/lib/image/object.h:57: undefined reference to `MR::Image::Mapper::map(MR::Image::Header const&)'
src\mrconvert.o: In function `ZNK2MR7ArgBase9get_imageERNS_5Image6HeaderE':
C:/Users/Jesse/Documents/Work/Research/FiberTracking/Software/mrtrix/source/mrtrix-0.2.11/lib/args.h:201: undefined reference to `MR::Image::Object::create(std::string const&, MR::Image::Header&)'
src\mrconvert.o: In function `ZN5MyAppC1EiPPcPPKcPKN2MR8ArgumentEPKNS5_6OptionEPKjS3_S3_':
C:\Users\Jesse\workspace\mrconv\Debug/../src/mrconvert.cpp:119: undefined reference to `MR::App::App(int, char**, char const**, MR::Argument const*, MR::Option const*, unsigned int const*, char const*, char const*)'
src\mrconvert.o: In function `ZN5MyAppD1Ev':
C:\Users\Jesse\workspace\mrconv\Debug/../src/mrconvert.cpp:119: undefined reference to `MR::App::~App()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

11:42:57 Build Finished (took 1s.854ms)
```

It would appear these are internal linking errors? How do I go about finding the source of these errors?

Comment: You need to add the library you're using to the linker options in project settings.

Comment: M M: do you mean where is the source code?

Comment: I am trying to compile MRtrix in windows in eclipse following the instructions here http://www.brain.org.au/software/mrtrix/install/windows.html . The source code is here: http://www.nitrc.org/projects/mrtrix/

Comment: -I"paths" is for includes. You need to use -L"path_to_lib_dir" so that g++can find the required libraries.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 0):

you need to compile all the files and link them together. It's either missing a cpp file or library

Answer (score 0):

This might be the problem. You need to use `-L` to specify where library files are. `-I` is to specify where included files are located.

```
g++ "-IC:\\Users\\Jesse\\Documents\\Work\\Research\\FiberTracking\\Software\\mrtrix\\source\\mrtrix-0.2.11\\lib" "-IC:\\Users\\Jesse\\Programs\\gtk+\\lib" "-IC:\\Users\\Jesse\\Programs\\gtk+\\bin" "-IC:\\Users\\Jesse\\Programs\\gtk+\\include\\glib-2.0" "-IC:\\Users\\Jesse\\Programs\\gtk+\\lib\\glib-2.0\\include" "-IC:\\gtkmm64\\include\\glibmm-2.4\\glibmm" "-IC:\\gtkmm64\\include\\glibmm-2.4" "-IC:\\gtkmm64\\lib\\glibmm-2.4\\include" "-IC:\\gtkmm64\\include\\sigc++-2.0" "-IC:\\gtkmm64\\lib\\sigc++-2.0\\include" "-IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\GnuWin32\\include" "-IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\GnuWin32\\include\\gsl" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o "src\\mrconvert.o" "..\\src\\mrconvert.cpp"
```

I think some of them shouldbe changed to `-L`. for example

```
"-IC:\\Users\\Jesse\...lib"
```

Should be

```
-L"C:\\Users\\Jesse\...lib"
```

And should go on the linkage line. i.e. The second line where you link everything.

Comment: all the includes are there because of previous missing header file errors. changing any of the -I switches would cause the missing header files errors to return.

Comment: Are you sure they have headers in the /lib folders? If they do then just keep that there and add the -L ones too. But on the second compilation step. Not on the first one. The first one only need headers since you are not linking.

Comment: however, the error points to 

    C:\Users\Jesse\workspace\mrconv\Debug/../src/mrconvert.cpp:123: undefined reference to `MR::parse_floats(std::string const&)'

which points to 

EXECUTE {
  std::vector<OptBase> opt = get_options (1); // vox
  std::vector<float> vox;
  if (opt.size())
    vox = parse_floats (opt[0][0].get_string());

Comment: I didn't really understand what you mean.

Comment: Oh you mean since the error points to the mrconver.cpp that the error is there? Nop the error is that it can't find where the parse_floats is defined. Which is in a library shipped with mrtrix. Somehwere in the lib/ folder of your mrtrix installation.